# How to remove this line on recycler view?

Tags: java, kotlin

[image: I can't removing this line in a very simple recycler view]

I can't remove that line on the recycler view shown in the image(above in the link)

The items row XML file is empty. It has a single card view, and rclrv view adapter also doesn't contain anything. But that line appears when I add an item.

Comment: Please add more details to the question or code snippet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a scrollbar then you can add this property to your xml

```
 android:scrollbars="none"
```

Comment: I tried it, it's not a scrollbar

Comment: @user22162843
Then we need more data. For example your XML layout fir item and  code for adapter